# plot for y=logx when x is between 1 and 100 in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

**Can someone help how to make a plot for y = log(x), x is between 1 and 100 in Python.** I have tried a lot to do it but cant figure out how to make it.

Comment: Using which plot have you tried?

Comment: Can you please post more information on what all you have tried till now?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Karthik. I am not getting that what values should I take for x and y to plot a graph. I am a beginner in Python.

Comment: Thank you Karthik! so nice of you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the matplotlib library. A simple scatter plot would come out of the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log

x = range(1, 100)
y = [log(xi) for xi in x]

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I also used the log() function from the math library.
In case you are coding in a jupyter notebook you do not need the last line of code

> plt.show()

You can end the cell with "plt"

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import log

x = range(1, 100)
y = [log(xi) for xi in x]

plt.scatter(x, y)
# some other operations in your code
# and you end with plt
plt
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Check this out.

I have used **SCATTER PLOT USING PLOTLY**  as plotly provides interactive features.

[image: Log chart]

You can refer more here https://plotly.com/python/line-charts/

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from math import log
x = np.arange(1,101)
ylog=[]
for i in x:
    ylog.append(log(i))    
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=ylog))
fig.show()

#for jupiter
py.iplot(fig, filename='Line-chart')
```